# Small caps italic as a separate font in LMTX

Tags: fonts, context

I have a font that has small caps and small caps italic as separate font files.
What I have now:

```
\starttypescript [sans] [dtl-documenta-sans-t]
    \definefontsynonym[Sans] [name:dtldocumentasanst][features=default]
    \definefontsynonym[SansItalic] [name:dtldocumentasanstitalic][features=default]
    \definefontsynonym[SansCaps] [name:dtldocumentasanstcaps][features=default]
    \definefontsynonym[SansCapsItalic] [name:dtldocumentasanstcapsitalic][features=default]
\stoptypescript
```

The issue is I want to access the small caps like an otf feature:

```
\setff{smallcaps}{\it Small Caps Italic Hamburgerfons}
```

I don't want to `\definefontalternative`, as it would quickly lead to confusion, and besides it seems that in my version of LMTX a lot of letter combinations for that command do not work.